Rutherford scattering closest approach distance
Consider a particle 1 moving towards a particle 2 at rest. In class, my teacher said that in order to derive the minimum approach distance when the impact parameter ( b ) is 0, we had to use conservation of energy in the center of mass reference frame:
$$ K_{CoM}=V(r_{\text{min}}) $$
With:
$$ K_{CoM}=\frac{1}{2}\mu V_{1,\text{lab}}^2 $$
And:
$$ V(r_{\text{min}})=\frac{Z_1Z_2e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{r_{\text{min}}} $$
Thus:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\mu V_{1,\text{lab}}^2=\frac{Z_1Z_2e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{r_{\text{min}}} $$
Yielding:
$$ r_{\text{min}} = \frac{Z_1Z_2e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{1}{{\frac{1}{2}\mu V_{1,\text{lab}}^2}} $$
I don't really understand why he used the total kinetic energy in the center of mass reference frame instead of just using the kinetic energy of particle 1 in the laboratory reference frame. Because both approaches don't yield the same answer.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Recoil of particle 2.

@Farcher Ok, I think I'm starting to understand but I'm still having some trouble visualizing how going in the center of mass referential makes recoil vanish ? Why exactly is there only potential energy ?

@Lucas In the CM frame the particles' momenta are always equal and opposite.  In a 1D collision this means that there is a moment where both particles are at rest (zero momentum.)  At that moment, there is no KE, only PE.

Go through this sequence.
Find the velocity of the centre of mass.
Find the velocity of the two particles in the Com frame.
Find the sum of the kinetic energies of the two particles in the CoM frame.
The answer should be $\frac 12 m_{\rm reduced} V_{\rm 1.lab}^2$ (your symbols) which is the total kinetic energy of the two particles in the CoM frame.

In the CoM frame the total linear momentum is zero and hence it is permissible to have both particles simultaneously at rest, zero kinetic energy, and this is when the electric potential energy of the system (two charged particles) is a maximum, the particles are at nearest approach

Thank you, I understand now!
